# Access Youtube API

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0, youtube-api, google-signin

I want to use [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list) to get the subscription list of a user. It requires oauth.

I read that implementing google sign in will make it easier to access this API

I followed Google's documentation and now I got the signing in working

[I have these files now](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin/app/src/main/java/com/google/samples/quickstart/signin).

**My question:**

1) Which sample do I need to use, `IdTokenActivity.java` or `RestApiActivity.java`

2) How can I use the sample code to access Youtube API? It doesn't say and the documentation is confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Which sample do I need to use, `IdTokenActivity.java` or `RestApiActivity.java` ?

`IdTokenActivity.java` aims at retrieving an `id_token`. The `id_token` is a JWT token designed to be sent to a backend to authenticate the user as a real (trusted) Google user. You can find more information about the flow for the backend [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/CrossClientAuth).

`RestApiActivity.java` is used to consume Google API which is what you are trying to do.

- How can I use the sample code to access Youtube API?

Here are the steps :

1. Go to [Google Signin setup for Android](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating), download `google-services.json` and place it in your `app` folder
2. in [google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com) enable Youtube Data API
3. add the following to app `build.gradle` :

   ```
   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
   compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.22.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
   compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-youtube:v3-rev182-1.22.0'
   ```

with `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to the bottom of your file

4. update the following to  your top level `build.gradle` :

   ```
   dependencies {
       classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
   }
   ```
5. Include the `RestApiActivity.java` in your project and update the following :

   ```
   // Scope for reading user's contacts
   private static final String YOUTUBE_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube";

   ...

   // Configure sign-in to request the user's ID, email address, basic profile,
   // and readonly access to contacts.
   GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
           .requestScopes(new Scope(YOUTUBE_SCOPE))
           .requestEmail()
           .build();
   ```

and when the client is authenticated (in `handleSignInResult`) , request the subscription list as following :

```
/**
 * AsyncTask that uses the credentials from Google Sign In to access Youtube subscription API.
 */
private class GetSubscriptionTask extends AsyncTask<Account, Void, List<Subscription>> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        showProgressDialog();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Subscription> doInBackground(Account... params) {
        try {
            GoogleAccountCredential credential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                    RestApiActivity.this,
                    Collections.singleton(YOUTUBE_SCOPE));
            credential.setSelectedAccount(params[0]);

            YouTube youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                    .setApplicationName("Google Sign In Quickstart")
                    .build();

            SubscriptionListResponse connectionsResponse = youtube
                    .subscriptions()
                    .list("snippet")
                    .setChannelId("UCfyuWgCPu5WneQwuLBWd7Pg")
                    .execute();

            return connectionsResponse.getItems();
        } catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException userRecoverableException) {
            Log.w(TAG, "getSubscription:recoverable exception", userRecoverableException);
            startActivityForResult(userRecoverableException.getIntent(), RC_RECOVERABLE);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.w(TAG, "getSubscription:exception", e);
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Subscription> subscriptions) {
        hideProgressDialog();

        if (subscriptions != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "subscriptions : size=" + subscriptions.size());

            // Get names of all connections
            for (int i = 0; i < subscriptions.size(); i++) {
                Log.v(TAG, "subscription : " + subscriptions.get(i).getId());
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "subscriptions: null");
            mDetailTextView.setText("None");
        }
    }
}
```

which is launched in lieu of `GetContacts` with :

```
new GetSubscriptionTask().execute(mAccount);
```

You can find a complete example [here](https://gist.github.com/bertrandmartel/7d323b09af889f5c03b862612c796046)

Comment: Thanks so much. I spent almost two whole days trying to figure it out.